# I am using modernizr and checking has class... but wrongly i am getting alert from 'firefox' borwser

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I am making a conditional function which is for ie8 or lesser, but i am getting the alert even in the firefox..

what is the wrong with my code?

```
var makeCurves = function(element){
    alert(element); //i am getting this alert even in firefox
    //ie throw the error as object expected
}
(function($){
    if(!Modernizr.borderradius && ($('div').hasClass('comCommunity'))){
        makeCurves($('div.comCommunity'));
    }

}(jQuery));
```

in case i use the code like this, it's working correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!Modernizr.borderradius && ($('div').hasClass('comCommunity'))){
        makeCurves($('div.comCommunity'));
    }    
})
```

is anything wrong with my self invoking function?

Comment: What version of Firefox?

Comment: i am using 17.0.1 versioned, as well can you check my updated code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure but maybe Modernizr checks for "border-radius" and your Firefox version doesn't support the CSS3 feature? Firefox definitely supports "moz-border-radius" though..